How to get the callback of Google's OAuth2 to process it as a route handler?
I've deployed a web app through ExpressJs and I host it on Google Cloud Run.
The issue I'm having is that I'm not getting the callback from Google's OAuth2.
I have a route handler set as "app.get('/oauth2callback', async (req,res)) and the REDIRECT_URI parameter of the OAuth2 client object ends as "/oauth2callback".
The route handler is not getting executed and I don't know why.
I confirmed that the authentication ends successfully, so I should get the callback.
In addition, the server is only listening for that callback, because there is no other request at the same time.
Hopefully you can give me any clue.
Thanks!

Take a look at the following options:

Check your Cloud Run ingress settings. You can set it with the following options: Internal, Internal and Cloud Load Balancing, or All

Check your logs and the console to see why it's not getting a callback.

Take a look at the official documentation of OAuth 2.0, make sure that you didn't miss anything such as having the correct redirect_uri. The value must exactly match the one in the authorized redirect URIs for the oauth2 client.


